# Retrieve value of certain key for every item in an ordered dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, kivy, ordereddictionary

Am having a hard time retrieving the value of name in every items in an ordered list like below any help would be highly appreciated.

```
OrderedDict([('12345', {'buyingprice': '600', 'category': 'Dairy', 'code': '12345', 'name': 'Dairy Milk', 'sellingprice': '800'}), 
('zsdfasfasf', {'buyingprice': 'test', 'category': 'Dairy', 'code': 'test', 'name': 'test', 'sellingprice': 'test'})])
```

To be more clear, i just want the value of key(name) for for every item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
names = [value['name'] for value in a.values()]
print(names)
```

output:

```
['Dairy Milk', 'test']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
names = [v['name'] for v in """your dict""".values()]
```

Creates a list of names by iterating over the values of the dict and accessing the 'name' key of each nested dict.